# Writting in a std::vector of std::vectors in the first dimension

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a `std::vector` of `std::vectors` and I want to use a for loop to push back one element to each inner vector. The code looks like this, but clearly does not work because you cannot access each of the vectors in that way (`matrix[i] =`) and line 8 produces a `Segmentation Fault` .

```
std::vector<std::vector<float> > matrix;

for (size_t j = 0; j < number_of_columns; ++j) {

  vector<float> elements_to_push = compute_elements();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_rows; ++i) {
    matrix[i].push_back(elements_to_push[i]);
  }

}
```

So, I would like to write the elements column-wise. Writing row-wise is not an option for me because I need to use some external functions that expect the elements to be in that order.

I think that a solution involves using a vector of pointers (`std::vector<float*>`) but I would like to know if it is possible to do it using vectors only as this simplifies things.

Also, it would be the best if the solution does not involve C++11 or later functionality because I have to keep backwards compatibility. However, if you have an answer that uses C++11 or later you can still write it for anyone else who might find it useful.

Comment: Just `matrix.push_back(elements_to_push);` without the loop `for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_rows; ++i) {` or even `matrix.push_back(compute_elements());`

Comment: @DimChtz Why not write that as an answer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am sure someone else will :)

Comment: Wouldn't this just push a row in the matrix? I will test that, but that was my belief and I did not try it.

Comment: @Grey The outer loop is necessary, the inner not so much.

Comment: @DimChtz But in this way the outer vector is of size 2000 and the inner vector is of size 1 whereas I want something like 1000 (for j) and 2 (for the i). I used `matrix.size()` and `matrix[0].size()` to find out the size.

Comment: @Grey Just noticed that your loops is kinda reversed. You use the first one for the columns and the second one for the rows. Does this mean that `elements_to_push` is actually a column to be pushed in matrix?

Comment: @DimChtz Yeah, that is my intension. To push a column to the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you computed and pushed rows instead of columns. However here is a solution (since you already know the size of matrix):

```
std::vector<std::vector<float> > matrix(number_of_rows, std::vector<float>(number_of_columns, float()));

for (size_t j = 0; j < number_of_columns; ++j) {
   vector<float> elements_to_push = compute_elements();
   for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_rows; ++i) {
       matrix[i][j] = elements_to_push[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a wrapper around a single `std::vector` in row-major configuration to represent your matrix, making it more convenient to work with than a 2D `std::vector`. The following should be compatible with pre-c++11 which is why I haven't used `auto` and some other c++11 onwards features...

```
template<typename Ty>
class matrix {
    // enables use of [][] on matrix objects
    class proxy_row_vector {
    public:
        proxy_row_vector(std::vector<Ty>& _vec, std::size_t cols, std::size_t row_ind)
            : vec(_vec), columns(cols), row_index(row_ind) {}
        const Ty& operator[](std::size_t col_ind) const {
            return vec[row_index*columns + col_ind];
        }
        Ty& operator[](std::size_t col_ind) {
            return vec[row_index*columns + col_ind];
        }
    private:
        std::vector<Ty>& vec;
        std::size_t row_index;
        std::size_t columns;
    };
public:
    // construct rows*cols matrix with default-inserted Ty instances
    explicit matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
        : mtx(rows*cols), rows_(rows), cols_(cols) {}
    std::size_t rows() const { return rows_; }
    std::size_t columns() const { return cols_; }
    // used for const [][] access
    proxy_row_vector operator[](std::size_t row_ind) const {
        return proxy_row_vector(mtx, cols_, row_ind);
    }
    // used for mutable [][] access
    proxy_row_vector operator[](std::size_t row_ind) {
        return proxy_row_vector(mtx, cols_, row_ind);
    }
    // insert a new row at the end
    void push_row(const std::vector<Ty>& row_vec) {
        for (std::vector<Ty>::iterator it = row_vec.begin(); it < row_vec.end(); ++it) 
            mtx.push_back(*it);
        ++rows_;
    }
    // insert a new column at the end
    void push_column(const std::vector<Ty>& col_vec) {
        insert_column(cols_, col_vec);
    }
    // insert a row at indicated position
    void insert_row(size_type row_pos, const std::vector<Ty>& row_vec) {
        mtx.insert(mtx.begin() + row_pos*cols_, row_vec.begin(), row_vec.end());
        ++rows_;
    }
    // insert a column at indicated position
    void insert_column(size_type col_pos, const std::vector<Ty>& col_vec) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < col_vec.size(); ++i) {
            mtx.insert(mtx.begin() + i*(cols_+1)+col_pos,col_vec[i]);
        }
        ++cols_;
    }
private:
    std::vector<Ty> mtx;
    std::size_t rows_;
    std::size_t cols_;
};
```

Then pushing a new column is simple, using your example:

```
matrix<float> mat;
std::vector<float> column_to_push = compute_elements();
mat.push_column(column_to_push);
```

---

*Note: In the `matrix` class above there is no bounds or size checking as it is a minimal example of such a class. You should add size checking in the row/column inserting methods to avoid trying to push a row vector or column vector which exceeds (or falls short of) the current number of columns or rows of the matrix respectively. Additionally you would probably want to add iterator support (trivial via `std::vector` iterators) and other methods (e.g. erasing rows/columns).*